# How to use the middleware for restricting other content based on the role? Using React Js and Laravel

Tags: reactjs, laravel

I currently setup the role based and content authorization. However i got problem when I try the to access the route of super admin still accessible. I used this instruction https://medium.com/justlaravel/how-to-use-middleware-for-content-restriction-based-on-user-role-in-laravel-2d0d8f8e94c6  - but still no working well.

to understand well, I will share to you what suppose to be the output and my sample coding on my middleware and api.php

1. I have Middleware of CheckRoleRouter.php
2. I create a unauthorized.blade.php file for new response if the user role access wrong route.
3. I already set the middleware to the kernel.php

Role: I have Super Admin = 0 and Admin = 1

**Middleware:**

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Auth;

class CheckRoleRouter
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        //Role of users

        //Super Admin = 0
        //Admin = 1

        // how to make a middleware to prevent accessing other router based on their role.
        if ($request->user() && $request->user()->role != 0)
        {
            return new Response(view('unauthorized')->with('role', 'SUPERADMIN'));
        }


        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

**Api:**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'App\Http\Middleware\CheckRoleRouter'], function()
{
    Route::get('list_offers','Api\BusinessOffersController@list_offers');
});
```

**Kernel:**

```
'checker' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckRoleRouter::class,
```

**Session:** - it means i used the admin role so the logic is the router of super_admin is not accessible anymore because i used the admin.

[image: local storage session role]

**Page:**

[image: Super Admin Page]